# How do I configure an Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS application with a Classic Load Balancer to use HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application that is running with a Classic Load Balancer. The Load Balancer is using an ACM SSL certificate. The NodeJS app is running an HTTP server on Port 8080, that, when accessed, redirects to the HTTPS server that is running on Port 3000. However, this does not seem to work. Neither server will load anything. Currently, my load balancer is listening on Port 80 and sending to Instance port 80, and listening on Port 443 and sending to instance port 443 with the ACM SSL cert. How should I configure my EB application, Load Balancer, and nodeJS app to make this work?

---

EDIT: As is default for Elastic Beanstalk applications, there is an nginx instance also running. My bad for not mentioning that.

As per @kgiannakakis's advice, My nodeJS app is now as follows:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var routes = require("./routes");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('port',port)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.enable('trust proxy')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
})

function init() {
    app.get('/', routes.index);

    app.get("/ping", function(req, res){
        res.send("Ok");
        res.end();
    });

    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
        console.log("App running on port %s.",app.get('port'));
    });
}

init();
```

HTTP requests work fine, however, HTTPS does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an ACM certificate, I am assuming that you are terminating SSL at the Load Balancer level. This means that the communication between the load balancer and the Elastic Beanstalk instances will be unencrypted. For your Node.js server you only need to listen to the proxy port (8080). The details are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html). You should note that:

- The port that your application listens on doesn't affect the port that the nginx server listens to receive requests from the load balancer.
- The default port is 8080 for Amazon Linux 2.

In your Classic Load Balancer you should add two listeners. One for port 80 redirecting to 80 and one to 443 with the certificate, also redirecting to 80. The Nginx server in your instances listens to port 80 and forward the request to your node server.

[image]

Please also note that it is possible to terminate SSL at the instances. This requires your own certificate (not through ACM) and properly configuring nginx. Read the details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html).

Comment: This works for HTTP requests, but HTTPS requests still result in nothing.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Also, you shouldn't check in your code for secure requests. All requests will be unencrypted.

Comment: The only error I can see in the logs comes from nginx, and is `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

Comment: Make sure that the instance port is 80 and instance protocol HTTP both for HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Awesome, that works. It seems that for some reason those changes had been reset upon redeployment. Is there a reason this could be happening?

Comment: Redeployment shouldn't change environment configuration.

Comment: "This means that the communication between the load balancer and the Elastic Beanstalk instances will be unencrypted." This is true for the default Elastic Beanstalk configuration, but bot necessarily true for all configurations. Many regulatory requirements require end-to-end encryption, which people usually configure by adding an SSL certificate to the Nginx configuration on the server.

Comment: @MarkB true, but this means that you need to bring in your own certificate, which the OP didn't mention about it. Regulatory environments also mandate to have port 80 closed all the time. This is difficult to achieve with EB, so in this cases, perhaps it is better to create your own launch templates and auto scaling groups.

Comment: Yes the OP left out many important details. I just didn't want people seeing your answer and thinking it wasn't possible to achieve end-to-end encryption on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: You are correct. I will edit the answer accordingly.